# API to find Latitude and Longitude based on Unique Well Identifier(UWI) info Canada

Tags: geospatial, api

I'm looking for an Open Source API to find out Latitude and Longitude based on provided LSD or Section or UWI info of Alberta and BC province of Canada.

Any help.

Comment: Is https://www.ntsfinder.com/help/api helpful? As I'm sure you already know, the UWI itself contains NTS Map Sheet number where the well is situated.